# How to find row index for a child component in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a component inside which 2 child components are there inside a  tag , This two components can be added multiple rows like how we add rows dynamically.

```
<template for:each={myprodlst} for:item="pi" for:index="index">
    <tr>
      <c-picklistutilitylwc value={pi.pi.TestF__c} index={index}
               object-name="TestObj__c" field-name="TestF__c"
       onselected={handleChange}></c-picklistutilitylwc>
    </tr>
    <tr>                                        
        <c-multicheckboxlwc class="objpick" object-name="TestObj__c"
           field-name="TestField__c" dependent-key={pi.pi.TestF__c}
                disabled={readOnly} get-label="false" index={index}
        value={pi.pi.TestField1__c}></c-multicheckboxlwc>   
    
    </tr>
</template>
```

on change of `picklistutilitylwc` value `handlechange` is called which is event dispatched from `picklistutilitylwc` component.

at this point i am getting which row the picklist value is changed and i am refreshing the `multicheckboxlwc` component by calling `multicheckboxlwcmethodCall`() as below using `template.queryselector()`
JS

```
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.getselectedpickvalue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail)).changes
    var intValueIndex = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail)).index
    var objectionPickList = this.template.querySelector('.objpick').multicheckboxlwcmethodCall();
  }
```

The issue i am facing now if i am changing the picklist component in row-index 1, `multicheckboxlwc` are row-index 0 is getting refreshed. Basically i am unable to get `multicheckboxlwc` component at row-index 1.

Any idea please how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use "querySelectorAll" instead to get all elements, then access the appropriate index from that result:

```
var objectionPickList = this.template
  .querySelectorAll('.objpick')[intValueIndex].multicheckboxlwcmethodCall();
```

Comment: Hi Sfdcfox. one question.. this above child component method needs to be called from handleChange(event) function or renderedcallback().. if i need to pass refreshed value..